# SQL logical operator efficiency

Tags: sql, oracle, logical-operators

I know doing an explain plan on the 2 queries below will yield the same cost, but **will the database evaluate both parts of an `OR` condition or will it stop after the first part that evaluates to `true`?**

```
select 1 from dual where
exists (select 1 from small_table where col1 = 10)
or
exists (select 1 from big_table where col1 = 10);
```

Swap the 2 exists conditions:

```
select 1 from dual where
exists (select 1 from big_table where col1 = 10)
or
exists (select 1 from small_table where col1 = 10);
```

#### An example of why this would matter:

Say one of the subqueries uses a table with millions of records (`big_table`) and the other part uses a table with only a couple hundred records (`small_table`). I know that the record I'm searching for is *more likely* to be in `small_table`, but could sometimes be in `big_table`. In this case, I would want to order the `OR` condition with the `small_table` first. If this were java...

```
String a = "small";
if (a == "small" || a == "big") {
    // a == "big" won't get executed
}
```

Comment: The database is free to run those expressions in any order it likes. But with the `EXISTS` operator it doesn't really matter that much as the database will stop after the first row it finds - and if the column in the `where` condition is indexed that is a pretty efficient lookup

Comment: It very much depends on statistics and information stored in the tables. The optimizer might consider from statistics to do a lookup only on the `small_table`, if he has cardinality information (in the form of statistics) about that value in `small_table`. Otherwise, if he doesn't have information about this, then it will do a lookup on `big_table`, or it will do a lookup in both tables (sounds crazy, maybe) if there are no reliable statistics to point to which table (small or big) might have the value that you're checking for.

Comment: Since this question is closed because it is a duplicate, I posted an answer in the "old thread" (linked to at the top). In short: if you need to be 100% sure of the order of evaluation, you can rewrite your condition using a tool that guarantees order of evaluation and short-circuiting. I give an example of rewriting an OR condition with a CASE expression (see the old thread).